# Rijndael Encryption and Decryption does not work on another computer

Tags: vb.net, file, encryption, rijndael

First of all, if i do encryption and decryption on the same computer, it works fine. Bu when i want to decrypt a file which encrypted on another computer with same key, it does not work. Error tells 'Parameter is invalid'. Here are the defines;

```
Dim cspp As New CspParameters
Dim rsa As New RSACryptoServiceProvider
Dim bVis As New baseVisitor
Dim encDec As New EncryptDecrypt
Public encFolder As String = ""
Public decFolder As String = ""
Public keyName As String = ""
```

Here is how can i define key;

```
Public Function GetKey() As Boolean
    Dim sonuc As Boolean = False
    Try
        keyName = "keyName25*-"
        If keyName.Length > 4 Then
            cspp.KeyContainerName = keyName
            rsa = New RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspp)
            rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = True
            sonuc = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        sonuc = False
    End Try
    Return sonuc
End Function
```

After getting key here is the encryption code;

```
Public Sub EncryptFile(ByVal decFile As String)

    Dim rjndl As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
    rjndl.KeySize = 256
    rjndl.BlockSize = 256
    rjndl.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    Dim transform As ICryptoTransform = rjndl.CreateEncryptor()
    Dim keyEncrypted As Byte() = rsa.Encrypt(rjndl.Key, False)
    Dim LenK As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}
    Dim LenIV As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}
    Dim lKey As Integer = keyEncrypted.Length
    LenK = BitConverter.GetBytes(lKey)
    Dim lIV As Integer = rjndl.IV.Length
    LenIV = BitConverter.GetBytes(lIV)
    Dim startFileName As Integer = decFile.LastIndexOf("\") + 1
    Dim outFile As String = decFile

    Using outFs As FileStream = New FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create)
        outFs.Write(LenK, 0, 4)
        outFs.Write(LenIV, 0, 4)
        outFs.Write(keyEncrypted, 0, lKey)
        outFs.Write(rjndl.IV, 0, lIV)

        Using outStreamEncrypted As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(outFs, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Dim offset As Integer = 0
            Dim blockSizeBytes As Integer = rjndl.BlockSize / 8
            Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(blockSizeBytes - 1) {}
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0

            Using inFs As FileStream = New FileStream(decFile, FileMode.Open)

                Do
                    count = inFs.Read(data, 0, blockSizeBytes)
                    offset += count
                    outStreamEncrypted.Write(data, 0, count)
                    bytesRead += blockSizeBytes
                Loop While count > 0

                inFs.Close()
            End Using

            outStreamEncrypted.FlushFinalBlock()
            outStreamEncrypted.Close()
        End Using

        outFs.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Encryption works for all computers. But Decription code which is below is the problem;

```
Public Sub DecryptFile(ByVal enFile As String)
    Dim rjndl As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()
    rjndl.KeySize = 256
    rjndl.BlockSize = 256
    rjndl.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    Dim LenK As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}
    Dim LenIV As Byte() = New Byte(3) {}
    Dim outFile As String = enFile

    Using inFs As FileStream = New FileStream(enFile, FileMode.Open)
        inFs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        inFs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        inFs.Read(LenK, 0, 3)
        inFs.Seek(4, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        inFs.Read(LenIV, 0, 3)
        Dim lenK32 As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(LenK, 0)
        Dim lenIV32 As Integer = BitConverter.ToInt32(LenIV, 0)
        Dim startC As Integer = lenK32 + lenIV32 + 8
        Dim lenC As Integer = CInt(inFs.Length) - startC
        Dim KeyEncrypted As Byte() = New Byte(lenK32 - 1) {}
        Dim IV As Byte() = New Byte(lenIV32 - 1) {}
        inFs.Seek(8, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        inFs.Read(KeyEncrypted, 0, lenK32)
        inFs.Seek(8 + lenK32, SeekOrigin.Begin)
        inFs.Read(IV, 0, lenIV32)
        Dim KeyDecrypted As Byte() = rsa.Decrypt(KeyEncrypted, False)
        Dim transform As ICryptoTransform = rjndl.CreateDecryptor(KeyDecrypted, IV)

        Using outFs As FileStream = New FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create)
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            Dim offset As Integer = 0
            Dim blockSizeBytes As Integer = rjndl.BlockSize / 8
            Dim data As Byte() = New Byte(blockSizeBytes - 1) {}
            inFs.Seek(startC, SeekOrigin.Begin)

            Using outStreamDecrypted As CryptoStream = New CryptoStream(outFs, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write)

                Do
                    count = inFs.Read(data, 0, blockSizeBytes)
                    offset += count
                    outStreamDecrypted.Write(data, 0, count)
                Loop While count > 0

                outStreamDecrypted.FlushFinalBlock()
                outStreamDecrypted.Close()
            End Using

            outFs.Close()
        End Using

        inFs.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Using same key must solve the problem but it error all the time. I searched everywhere. Is there anybody to help me?

NOTE : I just want to encrypt-decrypt jpg files

Comment: You’re using RSA to transfer your symmetric key. Do you have the same RSA key on all of your computers? (Probably not). Also, don’t change Rijndael.BlockSize to 256. Leave it at 128, and, better yet, change to AES.Create().

Comment: @bartonjs i have the same RSA key. I used this container name 'keyName = "keyName25*-"' all of the computers. I didn't do anything else. if i use AES.Create(), does every computer have their own key?

Comment: Opening an RSA key by name just means you get the same one each time. When the computer doesn’t have a key with that name it just makes up (and saves) a new one (since you didn’t set the ExistingOnly flag). Unless you imported the RSA keys on the other systems, that’s your problem. (Using Rijndael with a 256 block size is a portability problem—not many things other than .NET Framework support it (e.g. .NET Core doesn’t))